# Кодировка "multipart/form-data" в Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, кодировка

Передаю форму с jsp на контроллер spring MVC. В форме передаются файлы и текстовые данные, соответственно выставлен enctype="multipart/form-data". Но когда данные принимаются на контроллере, с файлами все нормально, английский шрифт распознается, а вот кириллица - сплошные крякозябры. Если enctype убрать, тогда все в порядке. 
На просторах сети вычитал про фильтр для "multipart/form-data", но примеров в форме аннотаций не нашел.
Подскажите пожалуйста вариант решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался:

Вот полученный параметр: String shortname;

Решение: String value = new String(shortname.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

Выводит кириллицу.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так делаю, может тебе поможет этот образец кода:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void index(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            System.out.println(part.getName() + " ::: " + IOUtils.toString(request.getPart(part.getName()).getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Со стороны JS пакую вот так:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ssid", getCookie('SSID'));
        formData.append("id", id);
......
xhr.send(formData);
```